# How can I digest my Angular directives inside my sanitized HTML string? | AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest

I'm having trouble recompiling Angular code found in my $scope.content object after it is inserted to the DOM via ng-bind-html-unsafe. Anyone know how to have Angular digest this code? 
Thanks a ton in advance!

[PLUNKER HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/tcPD6FHuGUqeGYU0NHTl?p=preview).

```
###index.html###
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <h2>HTML Testing</h2>
 <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="content.iPhone"></div>
</body>

###app.js###
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.content = {
    iPhone: "<div ng-style=\"style.iPhoneTest\">This shows up on an iPhone</div>",
    iPad: "<div ng-style=\"style.iPadTest\">This shows up on an iPad</div>",
    androidPhone: "<div ng-style=\"style.androidPhoneTest\">This shows up on an Android          phone</div>",
    androidTablet: "<div ng-style=\"style.androidPhoneTablet\">This shows up on an Android tablet</div>"
  };
  $scope.style = {
    iPhoneTest: {background: 'blue', color: 'black'},
    iPadTest: {background: 'black', color: 'white'},
    androidPhoneTest: {background: 'yellow', color: 'black'},
    androidTabletTest: {background: '#111', color: 'white'}
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a directive instead of injecting ?

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <h2>HTML Testing</h2>
 <div ng-my-phones="style"></div>
</body>

app.directive("ngMyPhones", function(){
 return {
   scope: {
    "style": "=ngMyPhones"
   },
   template: '<div ng-style=\"style.iPhoneTest\">This shows up on an iPhone</div>'+
'<div ng-style=\"style.iPadTest\">This shows up on an iPad</div>'+
'<div ng-style=\"style.androidPhoneTest\">This shows up on an Android phone</div>'+
'<div ng-style=\"style.androidPhoneTablet\">This shows up on an Android tablet</div>'
 }
});
```

Otherwise you have to use `$compile`, to tell angular to apply the scope on custom html, but this is a ugly approach.

If you want dynamically decide which phone to show, you may pass the `$scope.contents` array into the directive, `$compile` and append the element by hand like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
       <h2>HTML Testing</h2>
       <div ng-my-phone="content.iPhone" ng-my-phone-style="style"></div>
     </body>
</html>


 app.directive("ngMyPhone", function($compile){
  return {
    scope: {
      "ngMyPhone": "=",
      "style": "=ngMyPhoneStyle"
    },
    link: function($scope, $element){
       var oldPhoneElement; 

       //Everytime the phone
       $scope.$watch("ngMyPhone", function(newContent){
         angular.element(oldPhoneElement).remove();
         oldPhoneElement = angular.element(newContent);

         $compile(oldPhoneElement)($scope);
         $element.append(oldPhoneElement);
       });
    }
  };
});
```

[WORKING PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/oD5zl2anrmcex0klBUEI?p=preview)